# Validate information from the formBuilder's OnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need support to perform the validation of the components that the forBuilder loads with pathValue.

In my html component I have several tabs and each one loads a formbuilder with the necessary data and loads them correctly, only that some attributes are to place data in a mandatory way and it only validates at the time I POST the form.

What I need is for you to perform the validation at the start of the component either in the OnInit of the angular lifecycle or another cycle.

For this I am trying to use Bootstrap's Server side to report the .is-invalid and .is-valid.

I need an example or tips either in javascript so that my form can be validated the mandatory fields and inform it in the ap-vmessage.

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
      <label for="aluno-nome">Nome do aluno* <i class="far fa-question-circle fa-fw ml-1" placement="right" ngbTooltip="A alteração do nome do aluno só poderá ser feita via secretaria."></i></label>
      <input formControlName="nome" type="text" class="form-control" [textMask]="{mask: maskNome, guide:false}" />
      <ap-vmessage *ngIf="alunoForm.get('nome').errors?.maxlength && (alunoForm.submitted || alunoForm.get('nome').touched)"
                                                             text="O tamanho m&aacute;ximo do campo &eacute; de 120 caracteres">
      </ap-vmessage>
      <ap-vmessage *ngIf="alunoForm.get('nome').errors?.required && (alunoForm.submitted || alunoForm.get('nome').touched)"
                                                             text="O Campo &eacute; obrigat&oacute;rio">
      </ap-vmessage>
 </div>
```

Comment: you can use `FormBuilder` from `@angular/forms` and disable submit btn if it is in `invalid` state. and for preview error message you can use `mat-error ` tag for showing error messages